# Edits to posts should not immediately remove flagged items from Low Quality Posts review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Currently, if a post receives an edit while it is in the Low Quality Posts review queue, it is immediately removed from review. This feature was built around the old functionality of that review queue, where the system would identify potential low-quality posts based on its heuristics. The thinking is that if the post could be improved via an edit, it no longer needed to be considered for deletion.

However, the nature of that queue has changed with the addition of posts flagged as "not an answer" or manually flagged as "very low quality" by community members now ending up in this queue. This allows obvious non-answers to be deleted by the community after a vote, taking a large burden off of moderators.

This voting process is short-circuited by the immediate removal of posts from the queue with an edit by a well-meaning, but possibly mistaken, reviewer. I have observed several instances of non-answers making it through review in this fashion and being allowed to live on the site.

One such example is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537317/test-facebook-ads-api-sandbox/24580281#24580281) (now deleted), which is clearly a question being asked in an answer. It was flagged by two users as a non-answer and went into the queue. In the queue it [accumulated delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5223109), clearing the first two flags as helpful, but one reviewer chose to edit the post. That immediately removed it from review before it could be deleted and allowed it to hang around on the site. It took another user to flag it again for moderators to step in and delete the post.

The use of edits to remove posts from review might have worked with system-identified ones, but I propose that posts manually flagged by users not be removed instantly from review on being edited. At least posts flagged as "not an answer" should be prevented from being removed in this manner. It has caused many non-answers to slip through Low Quality Posts review, for a review queue that has otherwise been doing a great job of handling these.

This might be a feature request more specific to the way that reviews work on Stack Overflow, so I'm posting this here for now, instead of Meta.SE.

Comment: You basically want to remove the behavior descibed by bullet 1 under LQ Task in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). I do think this has network-wide impact...

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this. At least for the posts I have flagged the edits made to the post are almost never the total overhaul needed to make the bad post into a good one; instead, they range from correcting typos ("Eclipes" --> "Eclipse") to making the post not a crime against the English language (but still leaving the question VLQ). I have always suspected that this behavior has put the brakes on a deletion/close in progress (e.g. close votes quickly rising until an edit is made), but I haven't been able to confirm this. Nice to know that I'm not the only one with this concern.

Comment: That being said, I don't think the description of the VLQ flag really fits too well with current behavior. VLQ flags are meant to indicate posts where edits are unlikely to save them -- shouldn't that mean that posts should be scrutinized even after edits, since edits aren't likely to change the fact that they are VLQ? I think I understand why the current behavior was implemented, but I think it relies too much on the assumption that any edits made to the post would be significant, when that doesn't really appear to be the case. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'd like to see this change.

Comment: Given that we currently have an army of robo approvers together with an army of minor editors that edit just every turd, I would say that no edit should ever do anything automatically.

Answer (score 35):

As the OP has summarized the downside of the current behavior of always pushing a post out of VLQQ on any edit, there's a downside to simply keeping it in instead (and simply counting the edit as a "looks good"-vote):

The post stays as far along the review path as it was, even though what was reviewed before the edit and the changed post might lead to completely different judgements.

---

**Better to rewind the review completely on edit, than either further suffer the current behavior or using the no longer fitting reviews**:

- Remove all flags and mark them as helpful (The editors flags, if any, should just be removed) if they were not yet resolved (The flags certainly were not cast on the new revision).
- Remove all looks-good / recommend-deletion votes (maybe giving them back to the caster?) (same reason as for the flags).
- Reinsert into the queue with an auto-flag, maybe also one looks-good vote from the editor, and let the review recommence.

Comment: Resetting and recommencing the review sounds good

Comment: The problem is this could be abused.  Someone can just flag a question then edit it.  They get another helpful flag, which can quickly become a problem and add lots of inaccurate flags to the low quality queue.

Comment: @Anonymous: Ok, any flag the editor cast should then simply be removed, but neither as invalid nor as helpful.

Comment: Yeah, this raises good points. If we can do smart things like return the flags and notify the user that flagged to check again.. that might be an even better improvement.

Comment: @MikeM: It's back in the queue, so will be re-reviewed as appropriate. Being notified because I once reviewed that post would be a nuisance in my opinion, as well as unneccessary.

Comment: "The post stays as far along the review path as it was, even though what was reviewed before the edit and the changed post might lead to completely different judgements." Meeeeeh. You can also suggest a helpful edit then suggest a vandalism edit so they merge to get the vandalism approved. But nobody does that. Likewise, if something is so bad that it got into the LQRQ, most edits on the post are not going to be good enough make it not low quality.

Comment: @bjb568: The focus is not the wrongly accepted/declined flags (though avoiding either is a *good idea*). The focus is on not letting an edit break off the review, because there are known issues with many edits. Also, posts which are auto-flagged into the VLQQ sometimes really only need a bit of editing love (that *is* another reason for the queue) or don't actually belong there at all (it happens).

Comment: @Deduplicator From my experience, the situation where an edit changed how the post should be reviewed is very rare. There are three types of answers in the LQRQ (the questions there are all horrible and deserve immediate deletion): the ones which are horrible and deserve immediate deletion, the ones which are link-only or opinionated but *only because of the question which is horrible and deserves immediate deletion*, and the ones that were auto-flagged because they are horrible answers but are good enough to not warrant deletion. All three of these (99% of total) are not affected by edits.