# Is there a better way to deal with wrong or obsolete comments left from review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

The recent movement of answers flagged as "not an answer" or "very low quality" to the Low Quality Posts review queue has overall worked very well. It has cut down on moderator work load, inappropriate content is being removed, and I've seen few instances of good content being removed. I may [have my reservations about some of the delete votes that have been cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers), but those are usually balanced out to the point that answers aren't being deleted.

However, as we all are aware, some people don't read very carefully the things they are asked to review. One of the actions you can take in that review queue is to leave a comment for the poster explaining what you think is wrong with their answer. As a result, there are many comments being left on legitimate answers calling them comments, comments saying that answers which start with a hypothetical question should be deleted as non-answers, or complaints about detailed answers that contain links calling for them to be removed as link-only answers.

There are also many comments that are made obsolete when the answerer corrects whatever was questionable about the answer (providing more information to supplement a link, for example).

Moderators get "disputed review" flags for Low Quality Posts, and mostly the only thing I've been doing with those is to clean up these completely incorrect or obsolete comments. I've noticed that some other users have started to search through these and flag these comments for us to remove, which has also been helpful. Still, there are a lot of wrong comments being left, scattering noise across the site and irritating good answerers.

Is there a better way of handling these comments than relying on people to come across them and flag them? A good example of this are the link-based answers which have comments asking them to expand upon the link. A surprising number of these are indeed edited to contain more content, and thus these comments no longer apply. It seems like there should be a better way of automating the cleanup of these.

Given that the answers which legitimately deserve these comments are almost always deleted in review, would it make sense for them to "expire" and be removed by the system at some point? If an answer survives review, generally that indicates that it isn't too terrible, and the automated review comments on it are probably wrong or no longer apply. For link-based answers, maybe the comments could expire after an edit.

Are there better ways of handling these review comments?

Comment: If anything like this is done, [Edits to posts should not immediately remove flagged items from Low Quality Posts review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265485) is even more important...

Comment: I do not think the situation is as bad as you draw it up. In fact, I sometimes wonder why people press "Looks good" for old crappy answers that got upvoted, even when it is just about 1-3 scores as the balance. Also: `hypothetical question should be deleted as non-answers` -> I would definitely delete it if the answerer does not even care about proper English and it is just a wild guesswork. Also, some people reuse this argument for not getting silly "answers" deleted.

Comment: Allow comments to be flagged "I am requesting an edit", and if you do so you get notified when the answer attached is edited?  If the original poster does not `@` reply with "I did the edit you asked", tracking down that it happened is difficult.

Comment: @FinalContest - I'm referring to answers like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9285091/19679 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/694742/19679 that I've seen people vote to delete simply because they start with a question and the reviewers didn't bother reading any further. That's what I'm referring to there. Again, almost all answers that deserve to be deleted in review are.

Comment: How about introducing fragile comments: The one they are directed to may delete them at will... Or even, any flag against them will delete them, no action needed?

Comment: @BradLarson: to be honest, I would recommend the deletion of the first myself for the very reason of not being sure whether it is an answer or clarification, so I would personally think this is a question for clarification because otherwise it seems trivial so the answerer may assume s/he would miss something. It is confusing a language for an answer to put it that way, especially with language barrier. I think we should tell this to those people, and not the other way around: to accept confusing situations as always answer. _They should be clear whether they are sure or trying to clarify!_

Comment: @BradLarson: In all fairness -- when you see the answer before you see the question, it can be hard to tell that it starts with a rhetorical question and not a sincere one. Answers are written to be read by people who have already read the question, so reviewers are tricked into reading answers in a wrong and confusing way. This, plus the priming of having reached the answer via the Low Quality Posts queue to begin with, makes it inevitable that some reviewers will mess up. I don't think it's fair to assume that such reviewers "didn't bother reading any further".

Comment: I guess I would indeed just let them expire after a while. I don't really see a need for something more complicated or requiring more intervention.

Comment: I think a good solution for this would be to have the answerer flag the comments when they make the recommended changes. Either have that scenario auto-delete the comments, or have that be a separate queue for the Admins (or another review queue) to make sure that appropriate changes were actually made.

Comment: "irritating good answerers" -- don't put answers from higher reputation users in the review queue in the first place. These should be exempt from automatic queuing and reviewed by moderators if flagged.

Comment: I noticed, first time ever that one of my upvoted answers got deleted afaik.  It was a good answer, short and to the point.  Which is probably what got it axed, irritating indeed.

Comment: @HansPassant: link or did not happen.

Comment: @A.Webb: why? They are mortar as any other contributor. They should have no privilege what-so-ever, especially not moderators. If any, then gold badge holders in the area would be the most appropriate people to review.

Comment: Not sure why you think I'd make it up.  But if [you insist](http://www.lifeandexperiences.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/irritating1.png).

Comment: @HansPassant: Error 1011

Comment: @BradLarson: I would have flagged those for deletion. Probably wouldn't have added an automated comment. They stink of really being a comment and not an answer. While there may be somewhat of an answer in there, there are better ones in that post. The Jon Skeet one might be able to stay, but the one from A.H looks like a comment. I think the problem is more on the side of the answerers than necessarily the flaggers. The flaggers or recommenders for deletion usually only become aware of these problems through the various queues. So you would have to change the SO algorithm to 'hide' these.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't think people seek out to flag you or any other necessarily good, longtime answerer. These questions show up in the review queue using SO's proprietary algorithms and heuristics. So the reviewers see these automated reviews and act on them using the given guidelines that have been accepted by the community over time. If anything be upset at the system, not necessarily the reviewer.

Comment: @staticx - I don't either.  The problems with robo-reviewing have been well-featured at MSO.  I don't worry that much over a bad edit being accepted (for example), that's all easily correctable.  It does get to be a bit more critical when such actions start to delete perfectly good answers, just because they fit a "looks bad" red-button category.  Getting them undeleted is pretty hard.

Comment: @HansPassant: they will not get deleted if they are darn (i.e. perfectly) good answers.

Comment: Speaking about comments from review, I noticed that [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EqKDM.png) had two identical comments (the first two).

Comment: @Cupcake: And yet you added a third :)

Answer (score 10):

One problem I foresee with of Vote to Close's suggestion is that it doesn't solve the problem of the follow up comment from the OP of "I've updated the answer"; that *still* has to go through a moderator.

Instead, I'd like to revisit the ***age old*** request of notifications-when-a-post-you-commented-on-gets-edited.

1. A user posts a "Whilst this may theoretically answer the question..." comment
2. The OP comes and updates the post
3. The user gets notified, and dutifully clears up their comment.

Optionally, after #2, the OP could get warned that commenters will automatically be notified of their edit, and there is therefore no need to @ them themselves. This probably isn't needed however, as people will learn themselves eventually.

Now, I already hear the cries of **too many notifications**, therefore:

1. First of all, I don't see this as an issue.
2. We could only notify people on the first edit after their comment
3. If you're still not happy, *the first edit after their comment during a specific time frame*.

Comment: add to the end: 4. opt-out of it from your profile page? (I would really like such a feature but can understand if other people like to opt-out of it)

Answer (score 1):

> Given that the answers which legitimately deserve these comments are
>   almost always deleted in review, would it make sense for them to
>   "expire" and be removed by the system at some point?

This is actually close to something I've thought about recently. Some of us are aware how certain words in comments cause the comment to automatically be deleted on just 1 flag.

So I thought, why not use that for comments that are older than say 3 months, and contain the text related to auto-generated LQRQ delete reasons.

So that way people can just do a query for those comments older than 3 months, that contain that text. Then we can verify if the comment is obsolete now, since the poster edited/improved their post, and then flag the comment, and have it auto-delete instead of going into a very full moderator queue. (*for example, I still have like ~30 comment flags from 3-4 months ago that are still pending*).

But yea, if you guys/gals just want to auto-delete them by the system after like 1-3 months, have at it, I agree with that too.

**UPDATE**

After going through the LQRQ again today, I really think my first option would be the better option as of right now. Maybe in the future auto-delete them. But as of now, those comments should be deleted on the first flag by anyone, if the comment is greater than 3 months old (*or whatever you decide*).

The reason for this, is because it looks like not an answer flaggers are still finding a lot of not an answer posts that are pretty old. Searching by comments with the text of auto-generated comments to delete votes or just the text that a passerby could have left in a comment, can be a good way to find answers that might still need to be deleted as NAA or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the actions you can take in that review queue is to leave a
>   comment for the poster explaining what you think is wrong with their
>   answer.

I have noticed this too. The system shouldn't allow the same or similar automated comment to be stacked. If one has been posted, then recommend deletion should not prompt for a comment. It should go to the next item in review.

> There are also many comments that are made obsolete when the answerer
>   corrects whatever was questionable about the answer (providing more
>   information to supplement a link, for example).

Why isn't the answerer notifying the auto-commenter? It's a two-fold problem. Don't blame the reviewer. If this was a code review at a corporation and a comment was posted, then a response would be expected.

> Is there a better way of handling these comments than relying on
>   people to come across them and flag them? A good example of this are
>   the link-based answers which have comments asking them to expand upon
>   the link. A surprising number of these are indeed edited to contain
>   more content, and thus these comments no longer apply. It seems like
>   there should be a better way of automating the cleanup of these.

The answerer needs to take charge and notify the reviewer in the comments section that it was updated. If after some time, the person does not respond then the answerer needs to flag as **Obsolete**. We have tools to handle this. It is a process problem.

> would it make sense for them to "expire" and be removed by the system
>   at some point

That would mean the system knows that the answerer properly edited the question and addressed any perceived problems with it. You can't take the human out of the equation. The onus is on the answerer. If they don't have the time to edit it or care about the answer, then they should delete it if they don't want to fix the problems with it.