# A mechanism to warn reviewers to look twice before closing

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

You know how it is -- you're on the close queue and churning through the dross and suddenly you spot a question with 3 or 4 close votes that is actually not bad. Obviously previous reviewers have missed its true value and you'd like to not just vote to leave it open, but to leave a message for other reviewers to give it a second chance.

Yes, you can edit it and yes you can leave a comment in the general queue but what I would like is a "Vote to leave open" with a specific comment for later reviewers to consider (like the vote to close).

---

Two questions that prompted my question.

[Are compilers built with previous version of themselves protected from code injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681346/are-compilers-built-with-previous-version-of-themselves) was closed as a duplicate, but had an excellent answer by Eric Lippert. In my opinion this is not a duplicate (although the topic has come up many times) and little good would be served by trying to edit it.

[Storing input values in structs for fastest comparison later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860056/storing-eight-io-pin-values-efficiently-in-c) is a rambling question of dubious value which nevertheless deserves an answer. I couldn't usefully edit it, but I can try to answer it. The close reasons are about debug-my-code, which it definitely is not.

In each case I would vote to leave open and I would like to say why. Editing the question or dropping a comment into the mix would not achieve the purpose.

Comment: Maybe also an auto-notice if there was an edit since the last vote?

Comment: @Deduplicator if there's an edit, doesn't that kick the question out of the close review queue?

Comment: @Cupcake: Wasn't that only the VLQQ? (Where it anyway [under reconsideration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265485)...)

Comment: Where would the message(s) be displayed? - only in the queue? and where abouts would you put it?

Comment: Needs some examples.  Offhand, I'd say that such a warning isn't necessary; people know what closing is, and what the consequences are.  I personally relish casting the final close vote; in the vast majority of cases, the question deserves it.

Comment: Maybe a "vote to leave open" (as in -1 close) would work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good thing you are a moderator, so you always cast the final vote (unless it's already done).

Comment: @Deduplicator Only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I always prefer to give a chance than to close. Be positive is better!

Comment: @Kostanos: I'm positive that some questions are crappy enough to not stay open.

Comment: Isn't this what the Reopen queue is for? What about mixed vote closures (5-2 or 5-3) automatically getting put in there instead? That queue sees hardly any action as it is.

Comment: Rather than having a separate feature of "Leave a note for future reviewers," which seems a bit cumbersome (what if multiple reviewers add such a comment?) I'd be in favor of an automatic notification along the lines of "3 or more reviewers have voted 'Leave Open' on this question"

Comment: @Kostanos You fail to understand what SO is or what voting to close is. It is not just another forum. *Fundamental* to that is that we delete dross. Closing bad questions is the first stage of doing that. But it is only the first stage; the OP has an opportunity to improve a closed question *before* it is deleted

Comment: @Raedwald, Kostanos isn't saying everything should stay open, just that in doubt, don't necessarily close. This is particularly relevant for specific questions that require more expertise and when a reviewer considers that it's unclear, without having any background in the language or framework involved. ("I don't understand what it's all about, so it must be unclear...").

Comment: @Bruno: Yeah, I see lots of those.  "This question is nontrivial and succinctly stated, therefore I should vote to close it as unclear because it's not about debugging crappy PHP code."  I don't really know a solution to this problem other than asking people to avoid casting judgment based on ignorance.

Comment: I don't know if this is going to work. Shouldn't you always look twice (or good enough) before you vote to close a question? Besides that, if this warning-mechanism is used a lot, then I think it will eventually lose its value and people will probably ignore it all the time. And finally, if the people didn't see the value in the question, why would they see the value in it once there is a warning message?

Comment: @tmyklebu, I agree that this is not the majority of cases, but it also happens to be the cases than are the most interesting generally, for more experienced users who look for something a bit different and challenging. Closing them is a bit like throwing out the baby with the bath water.

Comment: @Bruno: Preaching to the choir.

Comment: Your one example question about compilers is really not suited for SO; it's a list question. The other is somewhat open-ended, as you say, "a rambling question of dubious value", but it may result in some good. I've edited out some of the fluff at the beginning, but while it may "deserve" an answer, keep in mind that Stack Overflow may not be the place to provide it. So you seem to be talking about saving questions that probably shouldn't be saved, and people "glossing over" questions that they probably _should_ be voting to close.

Comment: Your edit raises a serious question, though: if you really think the question is "of dubious value", then what the hell are you doing trying to keep it open and on the site?

Comment: @josh: I read the compiler question as a highly value and very narrow question about the "Ken Thompson hack", and I've now edited it to match. I vote down many questions, but these two seemed to me worth saving. Dubious just means I have doubts, where normally I have none.

Comment: Maybe hide the number of votes by default. They sway the reviewer's opinion.

Comment: Let say, you asking a question, good formatted, well organized. But some, currently online voters do not understand it, voting to close it, and finally close it.
But the question is good, well formed, organized, the only issue, that you didn't receive support of another 10 person who were not online for couple of days. Or even worst, these 10 person who could help you or understand your question, are not in stackoverflow yet, and there is no way to invite them, as the question was closed.
I believe we should close only abuse, spam questions, but not because somebody doesn't like it.

Answer (score 45):

When you see a question in the close queue* that looks like it's headed towards unjust closure**, and you think that other people don't see, or are glossing over, the magic that makes it a great question that should stay on the site and get answers, you should absolutely notify other close voters<sup>†</sup> using a special feature designed for precisely this circumstance, known as

## editing.

Edit. Edit edit edit. If you see something that other people don't, **edit** to bring it forward. Reword the question so that no-one else "misse[s] its true value". Edit out fluff. Make the title more specific. Rearrange the paragraphs. Fix the tags. Make the post shine in the real world the way it does in your mind.

Editing a question in the queue *immediately* removes it from the queue, drastically reducing the likelihood it will be improperly closed, and already-closed posts that are edited go into a re-open queue.

---

*By "close queue" I mean "anywhere on the site"

**Or is already closed

<sup>†</sup>By  "other close voters" I mean "everyone else on the site"

Comment: Is it removed from the review queue when you click 'edit' on the review screen, or only when you save your completed edit?  If it's the latter, I can imagine not being fast enough to save the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it's closed in between, it still goes straight into the re-open queue where it can be unclosed in short order.

Comment: My early experience on the edit queue was that changing a question too much just got the edit voted down. There is still the risk the OP will revert it. Yes, a valid point, even if it only covers part of my concern.

Comment: I didn't realize that editing immediately removed the post from the queue, thank you. In the past I usually leave a comment explaining why I think it should not be closed, and try to word it in such a way that its a valid comment even after the post leaves the review queue.

Comment: Certainly, it's easier to make bolder edits when you don't have to get them reviewed, @david.pfx.