# Disputing a close vote before actual close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

For this question (not posted by me), someone voted to close this:

[JavaScript/jQuery callback using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834122/javascript-jquery-callback-using-ajax)

...as a duplicate of:

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

...even though the question is not trying to return a response from an asynchronous call.

This question is not about that specific case, but more about the case where I'd want to dispute the close vote, not for *my* question, but for someone else's. I know that if the question ends up getting closed I can vote to reopen, but there doesn't seem to be a way inside the question itself to vote against the closing to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Comment: You can comment on the question to highlight why YOU think it's not a dupe. That can guide reviewers who may not close the question then. Short of that, nothing can be done.... and I'm sure it would be VERY complicated to make it work the way you want to without wreaking havoc on the way it currently works.

Comment: That's true, but I also wouldn't want to open a big comment thread of meta chatter on the question since I think whether something is a "duplicate" is often a contentious topic.

Comment: true that.... but again, I feel like having a way to counter close votes right away would be extremely complicated..... your "keep open" count as reopen votes or not? How many votes needed to close, since we can have people cancelling votes right away? it's not necessarily a bad idea, but I feel like it would be a MAJOR overhaul of CTV.

Comment: I would love to cancel the votes right away; a lot of people jump on the close train without really carefully reading the two questions for similarity as soon as the first vote is cast. Questions are often closed as duplicates when they're only slightly connected in topic (as in this example).

Comment: So, "slightly connected"... it depends. To me, as long as the answer means the original question can be answered (after you tailored the answer to your specific use case), then yes it's a dupe. I still get your sentiment though. Just feel like this is a MASSIVE Feature Request and would require a bit more of a post than what's done now.

Comment: The only thing I can think of after doing what @Patrice suggests is trying to find it in the CVQ and vote to leave open.  Also if you have a gold tag badge you could close it a reopen it to wipe it out.

Comment: The OP [there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266283/a-mechanism-to-warn-reviewers-to-look-twice-before-closing) suggests a "vote to leave open" which is close enough to what is asked in the Meta question here ("vote against the closing") in my book to justify closing as dupe.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question answers the question in the first link. Just because the title is different doesn't mean the dupe is incorrect.

Comment: See also [Allow "keep open" voting outside review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252010)

Comment: Maybe one of us can write a more generic canonical question; I see that particular question misapplied to anything relating to async + JavaScript all the time.

Comment: @Jacob In what way you want to improve that question?

Comment: It's not about improving it specifically, @AlexeiLevenkov; just if people want a canonical "all things async" question to use as a duplicate, that one doesn't work since it mentions "returning a value" not "doing arbitrary things in sequence." I really like the question as is, but am tired of people thinking it describes all situations.

Comment: @Jacob your new canonical will be really small - "sequential calls use the fact that function complete as implicit return value, which is covered in ..." :) What we really need is "PersonalHelp.SE" where questions that are duplicates can be migrated to and personalized help can be provided.

Comment: My point is that the OP had nothing to do with getting return values asynchronously, only executing something after an asynchronous completes... it's not a duplicate. It's fine if the canonical is small; so many people are missing the essentials of asynchronous (callbacks).

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend these three steps, in order:

1. **Edit it.** Right now, the question has a crappy title and the paragraph that follows *strongly* hints it's the same old confusion over how asynchronous calls work that we've seen a hundred thousand times before. If you've managed a more nuanced understanding, editing the question to put that front and center may prevent others from making the same mistake the first close-voter did.
2. **Reply to the dup-comment.** That's why these are comments - so folks can have a little discussion about the proposed duplicate. Politely state your disagreement and explain where you feel the voter went wrong (the edit you've made to improve the title and problem statement will save you a lot of work here), and give the voter (and others) time to reflect on it. Note that voters and flaggers can now retract their votes and flags, so informing them of an error can be extremely effective if done quickly.
3. **Write an answer** that clearly isn't the same as those on the dup-target. Identical answers aren't a guarantee of identical questions, but finding wildly different answers on two questions does tend to suggest that they're different questions.