# Who exactly deals with flagged posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, not-an-answer

When I'm doing reviews for "First Posts" or "Late Answers", quite often I will find that the "answer" is actually a comment, or another question entirely, which I normally:

1. Downvote
2. Comment on the answer, quoting the relevant section from the help centre.
3. Flag "Not an answer"

Which is hopefully the correct action to take.

Some time after one of these occurrences has taken place, I will check my flags summary to confirm that I didn't screw up.

When I see that the flag has been marked as helpful, I will usually click the link back to the answer at hand to see what action was taken by whoever saw my flag.

Often I find that **another high reputation user has also commented on the question, using more or less the same words as me.**

**Is this user the person who dealt with my flag?** Or, is it a coincidence, possibly they had the same review as I did.

I believe it happens too often to be coincidence, and I feel it happens very near to when my flag changes from active.

I ask partly out of curiosity, but also to determine whether I should bother flagging these things, if all the person dealing with the flag is going to do is paste the same comment as me.

---

*I would show examples, however all of the answers I've flagged are now deleted*

Comment: `I ask partly out of curiosity, but also to determine whether I should bother flagging these things, if all the person dealing with the flag is going to do is paste the same comment as me.` Keep in mind that, while all you see is the comment, these flags are actually being sent into a queue (as Brad Larson mentioned below) to be voted upon *for deletion*. What you *don't* see is the voting in the background that may result in the deletion of the flagged post. Reviewers have a set of standard comments that they can select from a list that correspond to their chosen deletion reason.

Comment: The comments that go with the reviews are automatic. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qfMUq.png

Comment: You'll get to join the review parade at 2000 rep. It's all I ever do now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"not an answer" and "very low quality" flags currently feed in the Low Quality Posts review queue, where they are reviewed by standard community members. From there, people can vote to delete, comment on, or take other actions for these posts. If enough people vote unanimously to delete a post, and it is not upvoted, it will be removed by the system.

These also go into the moderator flag queue, where we may also act on them before reviewers do. Frankly, I think that the Low Quality Posts review queue does a good enough job with these that we no longer need to see them, but that's how it is right now.

Posts that lead to contentious reviews, such as unanimous delete votes on upvoted content, generate automatic flags by the system which are only presented to moderators.

Anything you might flag with an "other" flag only appears to moderators.

Comment: At what point is the flag marked as no longer active in the first case, where a moderator doesn't see it?

Comment: @AndrewStubbs - For "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags: once a sufficient number of reviewers have voted or acted on it, once a single user has edited the post ([which I'm not a huge fan of](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265485/edits-to-posts-should-not-immediately-remove-flagged-items-from-low-quality-post)), or once a moderator has acted on it.

Comment: What information can non-moderator reviewers see about the flagger?