# Allow reflagging of posts marked "helpful"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags

With the advent of the VLQ review queue, I've come across on several occasions where I've marked a post as "Not an Answer", and the original poster or one of the reviewers made an edit to the post, but didn't change anything that would make it an answer. In these circumstances, the flag changes to "helpful", and it's immediately removed from the queue.

Right now, the flagging screen currently looks like this:
[image]

**In this example, I marked it as VLQ**, and the poster simply changed the link format around. It's still considered VLQ, and I can't mark it as such. It is an answer though, and I would receive a 'declined' flag, if I tried to submit it as a "Not an Answer", and a moderator reviewed the post.

The current course of action (For some of us in the SOCVR community), is to post to others to reflag the question so it goes back into the queue to get a second review. This is not needed, if we have the ability to reflag it, to indicate to the reviewers/mods that the post is still considered "Not an Answer" or "Very Low Quality".

**My recommendation: Allow flags that were marked helpful, to be reflagged.**

For further discussion, this was brought up in a few places, and I thought it should be worth a mention

- [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195078/keep-the-ability-to-flag-the-same-post-again-after-low-quality-flag-has-been-dis): A pretty much duplicate of this post, but at this time, flags became disputed and there was no possibility to flag again. At one point, this was changed to helpful, and the second post below adds an interesting solution to fix this:
- [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed/236884#236884): A good discussion, which mentions that edits made to a post, should mark the content as "disputed", which would solve the "abusing" nature that @Bluefeet mentioned below in the comments. Disputed flags (That ONLY meet the criteria of being edited in review), should be able to be reflagged for another review. This would solve the best of both worlds: Prevent possible abuse of the current system, where someone can mark a post as VLQ and simply edit it to gain helpful flags, as well as save the mods trouble by allowing it to be resolved via the queue vs. a mod flag.

Comment: What's going to prevent users from flagging the same answer 2+ times if they get a helpful flag?  I don't see why you'd need to reflag the same posts multiple times with the same flag type.

Comment: Why would we need to prevent it?

Comment: Sure seems like a way to boost your helpful flag count.

Comment: Then, just simply revert the helpful flag (Or mark it as disputed), back to pending. Don't have it add another flag.

Comment: Meh, that's seems far too complicated. You flagged it once, it was helpful, move on.

Comment: @bluefeet But again: The post is still considered not an answer. Why should I move on?

Comment: You didn't flag it as NAA, you flagged it VLQ.  NAA is still available.

Comment: @bluefeet Let's say you flagged an answer as "Not An Answer" (and we're assuming it really isn't). The post gets edited in review, marking the flags helpful. However, the edit still leaves the post as "Not An Answer". Should we need to raise a custom flag? Move on with our lives? Re-raising a NAA flag would make sense. That happens quite frequently actually (at least one time a day).

Comment: Why is this answer not an answer? Even if the link is removed, it still states "You can try Laravel's polymorphic relationships." That's an answer, even if it's not a great one.

Comment: @bluefeet That was an example that represents a VLQ problem. In the image case, I marked it as VLQ, and the poster simply changed the link format around. It's still considered VLQ, and I can't mark it as such. (It is an answer though, and I would receive a 'declined' flag, if I tried to submit it as such, and a moderator reviewed the post.

Comment: I've clarified the image shown @BradLarson

Comment: Honestly @Tunaki I only can envision users reflagging the same post over and over again after a helpful flag as a way to boost flag stats.

Comment: @bluefeet Why? I assumed the flag would go to a moderator queue, so only 2 outcome were possible: declined and that's it, or helpful and the post is most likely deleted. Both end the reflag cycle, don't they? *Edit:* wait I think I see what you mean: reflagging as VLQ over and over again because edits clear it and mark it helpful? Yeah that is... not so great.

Comment: @Tunaki [We purposely block it so users aren't raising the same flag over and over again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251302/164200). VLQ/NAA don't go to mods so there isn't a guarantee decline - an edit could mark them helpful which would allow gaming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every additional rule we add to flagging results in a system that's harder to explain, harder to understand, harder to fix (harder to even realize when it's broken) and in some cases harder to *use*.

Let's take a step back here...

### Flagging as a patch for insufficient permissions

The guiding principle behind the original design of Stack Overflow was that *everyone* was a potential moderator. See a problem? **Fix it!** Your participation earns you an increasingly powerful set of tools to do so, starting on [day one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) with the ability to write competing questions and answers, soon augmented with the ability to [up-](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and then [down-mod](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) posts, graduating into [full editing rights on every post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and eventually maturing into [the ability to **delete** other's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Given **enough time** and *the will to do it*, there are essentially no problems that cannot be handled directly by individual members of the site working together. This *dramatically* lowers the cost of moderating a site this size, by spreading the work out over thousands and thousands of individuals.

The only thing it requires... Is **trust.**

And that's where we started getting into trouble back about 6 years ago. The *untrusted* people flooding into the site vastly outnumbered those who had earned the ability to moderate. There was no guarantee that the folks looking at a given post would be able to fix it, or even know how. So flags were created as a way to *escalate* issues from the people who had no privileges to those who had some or all of them. Can't vote to delete? Don't know how to edit? Haven't earned downvoting privileges yet? No problem - flag it & someone will take a look.

### One step forward, two steps back

Flagging presents its own set of problems. Things like spam and overt trolling have been around (and had associated flags) from the very beginning... But those are *relatively* uncommon problems, and in most cases were easily handled by groups of flaggers. Some simple rules enabled them to work without moderator involvement in a majority of cases: 6 flags delete and lock the post, flags age away after a couple days if a quorum wasn't reached, and rollbacks eliminate flags raised on a now-discarded abusive revision immediately.

But "very low quality", "not an answer", "not a real question"... Those are much more subjective, and the solutions are less clear-cut. In theory, most quality issues could be resolved via edits; in practice, editing is labor-intensive and good editors are scarse. As tempted as I've been over the years to [status-complete Jon Skeet's old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/flagging-a-question-for-improvement-without-voting-to-close), the truth is that *very* few people are willing to step up and *fix* flagged posts; closing or deleting them is by far the most common resolution. Even among the few hardy souls willing to *try*, it isn't always obvious what can be done to salvage a problematic post. Finally, there's the matter of scale: anyone on the Internet can *create* a problem, but only a handful here can resolve it.

### Training wheels on a 20-speed

The end result of more widespread flagging then has been a concentration of responsibility among those who *handle* flags: first the tiny group of elected moderators, then the somewhat larger group of volunteers churning through the various /review queues. These hardy souls handle the vast bulk of flags raised on the site, and in some cases also *raise* a very large number of them... Which creates a profoundly odd situation:

**Many users empowered to actually fix problems themselves instead rely on flagging to escalate the problem... To themselves.**

If that sounds weird, that's because it is. But that's the situation you're describing in this proposal: you've identified a problem, escalated it to a group of users just like yourself, and - upon not finding it handled to your satisfaction - wish to escalate it *again*. Discouraged by restrictions placed within the system, you've resorted to calling on other users (most of whom probably share your privilege levels) to escalate it for you... Thus we have a situation where you're asking a group of users *who could all just fix the problem* to instead collaborate on formally asking a group of people just like themselves, a group of people who might actually end up being *the same group*, to intervene.

[image]

This is... Beginning to look very inefficient.

### Put down the flag, pick up the pencil

As implied above, flagging is by far the most efficient *initial response* to a poor-quality post... At least, short of just downvoting. Hands-down, it's the most *effective* initial response in cases where you know the common reaction from most mods and reviewers is going to be deletion.

But if you raise enough flags, you're gonna see a few of them handled incorrectly... Or at least, in a way counter to what most folks would consider appropriate. There are all sorts of reasons for this, but editing is far from the most common. A generous estimate puts VLQ flags incorrectly dismissed by edits at under 1% of flags, so we're talking maybe one out of every hundred if those errors are distributed evenly. And at that point, flagging stops being so efficient.

In cases where you absolutely *cannot* see a way to resolve a situation on your own, Brad's advice is fine. Realistically, the system would almost certainly do exactly the same thing even if you *did* manage to get another flag raised on the post - at some point, it just isn't sane to keep doing the same thing and hoping for different results, so elected moderators get called in to resolve it. Given there's already been some disagreement over the proper course of action, if your goal is to get the post deleted then it behooves you to explain in detail *why* you feel this is appropriate.

But you do have another option: **just edit the damn thing.** In your example, you're flagging a post that's... Pretty light on detail. So, add some details. You don't have to turn it into the perfect answer, just one that an interested reader can understand and make an informed decision on. Will this take you a while? Probably. Certainly a lot longer than flagging it did. On the other hand, you only need to expend this effort once for every hundred answers you encounter (probably less), so it's hardly a crippling burden.

### In conclusion

Flagging is a useful tool, *when used as a force multiplier*, used to increase the productive attention on a post. But don't feel that your hands are tied if a given flag isn't handled in the way you expected; you've earned quite a bit of trust on the site [since first you gained the ability to flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) - and ignoring those privileges puts you at a disadvantage. Use *all* the tools at your disposal when seeking to resolve problems here.

Answer (score 8):

If you have flagged a non-answer that should be deleted, and it was marked as being helpful due to a misguided edit, you can use a custom flag and explain what happened and why the answer should be deleted. I should note that moderators already get automatic flags for contested reviews or delete reviews on upvoted posts that mark flags as helpful but don't delete the post.

The reason you are using a "very low quality" or "not an answer" flag is to ask for immediate deletion of a post. You should be able to justify such a deletion in a custom moderator flag, if it is warranted, without having to put something into a second cycle of review.

What you're talking about here is treating a symptom when there might be a deeper problem. I [have concerns about how edits can allow non-answers to pass through review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265485/edits-to-posts-should-not-immediately-remove-flagged-items-from-low-quality-post), and it might be best to address that at the source. There shouldn't need to be a reason to re-flag something.

There are problems with allowing someone to continually re-flag the same post with the same flag. We see this with comment flags, where people will regularly flag and re-flag the same innocuous comment in order to have it destroyed. They're perhaps hoping to annoy moderators into bending to their will or to spin the wheel to see if they can get someone more to their liking.

Restricting this to only helpful flags would still allow for potential flag-farming or attacks against specific posts by sending them through Low Quality review multiple times. It's probably best to allow a single flag of a default type, then force people to explain themselves in custom flags after that.

Comment: So the best case in these circumstances is to simply mark the post for moderator intervention? (Also, quick side note question. Does the moderator flags follow the same markdown syntax for comments. Can I use things like [link here](http://example.com) without you seeing `[link here](http://example.com)`?)

Comment: @FrankerZ - I'm pretty sure flags aren't rendered on our end using markdown, just raw text. I also use a userscript sometimes to fetch them, and that only pulls raw text. Links are automatically highlighted on our dashboard, so I recommend just using the URL and saving the extra characters.

Comment: Also, to follow up to your "Address the source" comment: If removing the item from the queue solves 90% of posts, then I don't think much needs to be done in this case. This only involves 10% of the posts, and usually happens from a mis-guided edit, which (In my case) has always been solved by a simple reflag. (I've always thought this added it into the queue again, but I may be mistaken, and it may go straight to the mods instead). If this is the case: Flagging for mod attention instead is most likely fine.

Comment: I've edited my original post with some further discussion. This was brought up a few other times, and I came up with another solution that could work (And would solve @bluefeet's abuse concerns.)