# NAA flag accepted, post left intact

Tags: support

Recently, I have flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154291/updating-images-in-file-service-azure-using-rest-api-invalid-header-value-conte/48698414#48698414) post as NAA.

> [image: NAA]

Flag accepted

> [image: Flag accepted]

...but the post is left intact.

From my usual experience, NAA-answers get removed upon being qualified as such. This wasn't.
It wasn't edited ever since, also.

What is the scenario that I've stumbled across?

Comment: At what time in UTC did you flag that exactly? The OP [deleted and undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48698414/timeline) causing some review tasks to be invalidated.

Comment: The review task that you handled was invalidated https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18768730 by the delete vote of the OP.

Comment: I've casted a new NAA flag. Let's see how this one goes.

Comment: Is it correct, that the post had been rightfully deleted, but the poster resurrected it?

Comment: They have that option. Not sure if they know that they invalidate reviews/flags that way

Comment: Should that be allowed in given conditions?

Comment: What are the drawbacks/let-downs if we forbid undeletion if it was caused by voting?

Comment: This post has been reviewed three times, deleted twice and every time the post owner undeleted it.  I'd say enough time and energy has been wasted on it already, a couple of downvotes can do the job better.

Comment: When a post is flagged by members of [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) the bots there keep track of posts that are flagged and when they are edited/deleted a message is [posted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=41179797#41179797) and members are pinged.

Comment: @rene, true but it does **not** work for delete and undelete (only for edits), mostly to retract flags and remove the answer from LQP/mod queue, if it does not belong there anymore. Well we also see some incorrect edits from the LQP queue that invalidates flags

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197964/320339

Comment: This [userscript](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts/blob/master/reflagreview.user.js) by [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) however will find these, it checks which post you have helpful flag and post was not deleted.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to reverse the duplicates. In my opinion, this question is better than the duplicate and has answers. It would be nice if a moderator or gold tag badge holder could reopen this question and edit the duplicate list of the other one to add this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Martijn and others explain, you hit an edge case. You correctly flagged this as "not an answer", but the answerer themselves deleted the post before it was reviewed by the community and moderators. This marked your flag as helpful. They then undeleted the post, which they can do for anything they've deleted.

In cases like this, or [when people mistakenly edit non-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265485/edits-to-posts-should-not-immediately-remove-flagged-items-from-low-quality-post) (thus clearing flags and kicking them out of review), my recommendation is to file a custom flag and point out what happened. Moderators can then delete the post, and our votes can't be overturned by a single undelete vote.

In cases where something was deleted in review and the user undeleted it after that, [we do get an automatic system flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/135615) so that we can process these. This is a case where we don't get such an automatic flag, so a manual one is best.

Answer (score 1):

As **@rene** explained, the flag is **fair** and the post was deleted, but it has been undeleted by the author who has the privilege to do that. It has been subsequently [deleted and undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48698414/timeline) multiple times thereafter, which resulted in invalidation of all previous/subsequent reviews.

In order to decrease the chance for undeletion (which as of now is possible), these posts can be commented accordingly to let new user understand the reason.

Comment: I do not believe the OP can undelete posted deleted via review.  If you look at the timeline, the post was deleted and undeleted by the OP himself.  Each time invalidated the open flags

Comment: So wait a minute. This particular OP, who quite obviously *does not understand the rules* and/or *does not understand enough English* to grasp what we're trying to convey ... this OP can go on with the continuous (trolling-like) undeleting as long as he likes? Comming again and again?

Comment: *until someone mod flags or maybe if enough times (delete/undelete) an automatic mod flag is raised*

Comment: It is now moderator deleted, which means the OP can't undelete it now.

Comment: The auto-flag wasn't raised because the OP deleted the answer *themselves* before enough NAA flags had accumulated for it to be deleted from the queue. This cleared the flags, and the OP undeleted again. They then deleted and undeleted another time (before more flags came in). This is not necessarily done deliberately to clear the flags, just inexperience with the site can also lead to this behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in this case, why my flag was `helpful` (not disputed/declined due to (un)deletion)? Are flags considered individually?

Comment: @Hexfire it was automatically marked as helpful when the post was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it all sounds as a lot of work has yet to be done by site devs...

Comment: Also, @MartijnPieters I think you can add a more complete answer to this. Mine appears to miss some notable points.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "post authors can always undelete posts deleted by low-rep users via /review..." ([from official explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/165773)). If you think of it this makes good sense, except that moderators would better pay closer attention to system flags raised when this happens

Comment: @gnat Ok, I missed that one.  I was basing my assessment of the undelete rules on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/can-the-owner-of-a-question-undeleted-it-with-his-vote-alone-can-he-undelete-it

Comment: @psubsee2003 no, not at all - compare dates of these MSE explanations. Older one refers to high rep users deleting the post - 10K for questions, 20K for answers (implicitly because at that time low rep users couldn't delete anything at all). Newer explanation explicitly mentions that it relates to low rep users - implicitly assuming that for higher rep ones deletion keeps working the way it did before